# How do I get the next pagination 'href'?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I am having trouble obtaining the href link for the next pages of the url. I got up to obtaining all the text and what not that the tag contains but I can't seem to wrap my head around to removing the text that I don't need and just obtaining the href and navigating through the pages.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
import time

jobsearch = input("What type of job?: ")
location = input("What is your location: ")
url = ("https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=" + jobsearch + "&l=" + location)
base_url = 'https://ca.indeed.com/'

r = requests.get(url)
rcontent = r.content
prettify = BeautifulSoup(rcontent, "html.parser")

filter_words = ['engineering', 'instrumentation', 'QA']
all_job_url = []
nextpages = []
filtered_job_links = []
http_flinks = []
flinks = []

def all_next_pages():
    pages = prettify.find_all('div', {'class':'pagination'})
    for next_page in pages:
        next_page.find_all('a')
        nextpages.append(next_page)
        print(next_page)

all_next_pages()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get the links of the search result items. Find `row  result` class and then find `a` tag, it contains all the information you need.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
import time

jobsearch = input("What type of job?: ")
location = input("What is your location: ")
url = ("https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=" + jobsearch + "&l=" + location)
base_url = 'https://ca.indeed.com/'

r = requests.get(url)
rcontent = r.text
prettify = BeautifulSoup(rcontent, "lxml")

filter_words = ['engineering', 'instrumentation', 'QA']
all_job_url = []
nextpages = []
filtered_job_links = []
http_flinks = []
flinks = []

def all_next_pages():
    pages = prettify.find_all('div', {'class':'  row  result'})
    for next_page in pages:
        info = next_page.find('a')
        url = info.get('href')
        title = info.get('title')
        print(title,url)

all_next_pages()
```